# How to get database entries in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do a project in ASP.NET MVC. This is my database structure.

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdnog.jpg)

and this is an action in my controller class.

```
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private myDBEntities db = new myDBEntities();

    // GET: Users
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Users.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Users/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Users/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserId,Email,Password,FirstName,LastName,Gender,Birthday,AboutUser",Exclude ="UserId")] User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Find(user);
            db.Users.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }

        return View(user);
    }    
}
```

and this is my database code that I used to generate database table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [UserId] INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Email] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [Password] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [FirstName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [LastName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    [Gender] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
    [Birthday] DATETIME NOT NULL, 
    [AboutUser] VARCHAR(1500) NOT NULL
)
```

Here I am trying to create a way for users to enter information about their email, first name, last name etc and when they do this I want these details to be added to database and when this happens I want an UserId to be generated. So in my controller's create method, I want a way to get the previous user's id. The first user who logins will get a id = 0 and after that I want to retrieve this id and keep incrementing it. So how do I do it?

TLDR: I want something like db.tableName.getRow()

Comment: Your `UserId` is already an auto-incremented field. You don't set it.

Comment: Yes I set it like that, but no one is adding UserId value into database right? From the view the user will only be able to enter everything except UserId, but nowhere in my code am I specifying the value of UserId to be entered into database.

Comment: Its an auto-incremented field - its done automatically!

Comment: Your TLDR is misleading. I thought you didn't have a data context because of it. Now I am not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: have you added ALTER TABLE [yourTable] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) for your primary key ?

Comment: What is a context? I just right clicked App Data folder and added a SQL Server Database and added tables to it and then when I created this controller with create template, I got this line added. private myDBEntities db = new myDBEntities(); myDBEntities is the name of my database in Server Explorer. So I need a way to access the data from the database or simply how do I perform SQL queries using this db variable.

Comment: @u.sureshkumar you need to narrow your question down to the exact problem you're currently having. Your question is jumping 5 steps ahead of where you're currently at and basically asking SO to do your whole project for you. Refine your question down to solve the problem you're currently facing, and you will get better help. I deleted an answer which may have been what you needed because of how much you're asking in 1 question (which is really about 3 or 4 questions rolled into 1) .

Answer (score 0):

Identity(1,1) means that are a auto increment, starting from 1 and increment 1.
For what you want (the first user starting from 0, change that to Identity(0,1) on UserId.

Comment: Yes I know that, but the thing is that I excluded UserId from my action. So no model binding for that meaning that I have to explicitly add it to the database and I just want to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Identity(1,1) means that your column is set to auto increment, starting from 1 and increments 1 on every row. It doesn't matter if you add this into model or not, this is the behavior of SQL that on every insertion it will get the maximum UserID, increments it by 1 and insert the record.

But since in your comments you are asking again about how to get the maximum UserID, so you could try this:

```
var Id = db.Users.Max(x => x.UserId);
var newId = Id + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

when using linq and you add the user the newly created id is bound to the user model.

as long as you have a primary key auto increment also

also you will never have a returned id of 0 , it will start with 1

so you can go

```
db.Users.Add(user);
var newUserID = user.userid;

return newUserID;
```

or when the record is added you should pass the user model back to a viewModel and pass that back to the view so the user can see the information they just entered.